# Script para deixar meu site (jogo) mudo

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, jogos

Tenho um projeto em localhost (joguinho em HTML 5, JS e CSS), ao fundo do game toca uma música, não consigo fazer com que o botão de desligar o som funcione, alguém conhece algum artigo que ensine ou método de fazer isso?

Desculpa faltou uns detalhes, o jogo em si não tem audio, a pagina é que tem um "audio" que vem de um video no YT, queria poder fazer um link que deixasse minha pagina muda :/

Comment: poste o seu código ai, o mais completo possível de forma que seja possível que façamos um teste e assim lhe ajudaremos melhor,.

Answer (score 4):

Se o audio vier da tag **audio**

```
 <audio id="musica" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="musica.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio> 


document.getElementById('musica').muted = true;
```

---

Visto que o vídeo vem do youtube penso que não exista nenhum parâmetro para vídeos embutidos que permita fazer mute ao vídeo.

De qualquer maneira deixo-te aqui um link
[Player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters)

O melhor será fazer download do vídeo e coloca-lo outra vez através da tag

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou :D